# Xcode, Instruments, Allocations, Command Line App, not registering free()

Tags: xcode, instruments

I have a very simple Command Line Tool in Xcode:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    void *p = calloc(32, 1);
    assert(p);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run Instruments->Allocations it shows one living block. The `free` seems to be ignored.

In the olden days, I remember that you could actually still use the last free'ed block. So I tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    void *p = calloc(32, 1);
    assert(p);
    free(p);
    void *q = calloc(32, 1);
    assert(q);
    free(q);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, Instruments->Allocations shows no living blocks. This seems correct.

Can anyone explain or reproduce the problem I am seeing in the first program?

I'm using Xcode 4.1.1

Thanks.

Comment: *sidenote:* always use the latest Xcode version

Comment: Pretty funny, Xcode 5 optimizes away the alloc/free so there are no blocks allocated. But the problem in my bigger case ( too big too post ) remains. I'll try some other approaches to display the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase the comments above.

[Apple LLVM](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/) in Xcode 5 resolved the alloc / free behavior so that no blocks allocated now, thus the `free()` method runs as expected.